# The view dismisses when @ObservedRealmObject is updated

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I have a view where realm object can be updated, and when I do that the view dismisses, and that’s unwanted behavior, after the object is updated the view should still be on screen. What could be the problem here and possible solution?

```swift
struct CardView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var card: Card

    @State private var frontText: String = ""
    @State private var backText: String = ""

    @EnvironmentObject private var realmManager: RealmManager

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $frontText)
            Divider()
            TextField("", text: $backText)
        }
        .onAppear {
            frontText = card.front
            backText = card.back
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                Button {
                    do {
                        try realmManager.realm?.write {
                            guard let card = card.thaw() else { return }
                            card.front = frontText
                            card.back = backText
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Update")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How the view opens:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(deck.cards) { card in
        NavigationLink {
            CardView(card: card)
                .environmentObject(RealmManager())
        } label: {
            Text(card.front)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The likely culprit is one of those environment objects, start by not initializing environment objects in the body of a View. Use StateObject

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/two-swiftui-debugging-helpers-you-can-start-using-right-away-26d25630c0cf

Comment: even with @StateObject the view still dismisses

Comment: Then something in there is likely redrawing everything, this is the biggest disadvantage of ObservableObjects so much so that Apple is basically obsoleting them in iOS 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```swift
NavigationView {
// ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

I used this modifier on NavigationView and it did the trick.